# Why dependent RVs are treated as independent RV?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Draw 3 cards from a deck of 52 cards. Observed that the value of the 3 cards, then replace the card with the lowest value with another card in the deck. What is the expected value of the 3 cards?

ANS:

Let $X_i$ be the $i_{th}$ card drawn. Then, we are looking to solve

$E[X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4]-E[min(X_1,X_2,X_3)]$.

Focus on the second term, we let $m = min(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. Thus

$P(m\geq k) = (1-P(X_1\leq k-1))^3 = (1-\frac{k-1}{13})^3$.

---

**Confusion**: $X_1, X_2, X_3 $ are clearly dependent variables. But the line above, it seems to me that they are treating them as independent variables. I am confused!

Comment: I agree with you; this is wrong, and would be *obviously* wrong if we began by drawing $5$ cards, since then $\Pr[m \ge 13]$ would be $0$ and definitely not $\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^5$.

Comment: Yes, the solution is wrong for the reason you say, and also it should be $\min(X_1,X_2,X_3),$ not $\min(X_1+X_2+X_3)$

Comment: You can compute $P[m \geq k]=P[X_1 \geq k, X_2 \geq k, X_3 \geq k]$ by sequentially drawing and noting that we must first choose one of $4(n-k+1)$ cards larger than $k$, then (assuming this happens) choose one of $4(n-k+1)-1$ cards larger than $k$, and so on.

Comment: Let $V = \min(X_1,X_2,X_3).$ If we cheat and pretend sampling is with replacement then $R(k) = P(V>k) = [4(13-k)/52]^3$ and $E(V) = \sum_{k=0}^{13} R(k) \approx 3.77,$ the same answer as I get from simulating a million draws of three. Simulating a million draws of three without replacement gives $E(V) \approx 3.71.$ So the effect of dependence is not huge, which may have been the rationale for using independence.